# Display image in Pug/Jade template engine

Tags: javascript, express, pug, template-engine

I am trying to display images from an object for get Http method ('/campgrounds'). Get Http Method with campgrounds array have 3 objects with 2 properties
How to display the images links in the home page ?

```
app.set("view engine", "pug"); 
app.get('/campgrounds', (req, res) => {
    const campgrounds = [
        {
            Name: "Name1", 
            Image: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1571687949921-1306bfb24b72?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
        },
    ]; 
    res.render("campgrounds", { campgrounds: campgrounds });
});
```

This is **campgrounds.pug** page

```
html 
  head 
  body 
      h1 This is the Campgrounds Page!  
       each val in campgrounds  
        ul
         li=val.Name 
         li=img(src=val.Image) // get the images as stirng links
```

Answer (score 0):

Indent the `img` tag:

```
each val in campgrounds  
  ul
    li=val.Name 
    li
      img(src=val.Image)
```